# Creepy caller blocked, but still gets through to my voicemail

Tags: call-screening

I gave my phone number to someone who turns out to be unstable individual...crazy dude. I blocked him from my android phone, blocked from calls and messaging. Somehow he managed to call me, doesn't show the call on my call log at all..never heard or was alerted of the call. And he then left a voicemail and when I go through the menu to get the callers number it is silent..blank. How is this happening? And how can I block him all together? Seriously, this guy is freaking me out. Help please if you can.

Comment: Sounds like you blocked it at the Android level, but have you tried logging into your service / phone carrier's website and blocking the number from there?  At this point it may be worth switching to a new phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Blocking phone numbers on Android is not possible...

The work-around that developers use is a redirection to the voicemail number, redirecting calls to voicemail is the only option...

HOWEVER, From the Voicemail side & Mobile service provider's side, things can be blocked !

- Call your service provider and request the number to be fully blocked from ever connecting at all..  .

Alternatively ( if you don't use voice mail )

A workaround i found using the call setting....

• Change your voicemail number,
It is called ( redirect on unanswered ) an can be configured in the call settings.

I changed my number to +610   and it allowed the change. . The voicemail ( redirect service ) will redirect the call to a non existent number like +610 and then end the call ( They'll hear - "This number is not connected" )   .

Answer (score 0):

This would be a network / mobile provider solution, they would be able to blacklist a number for you and prevent it from connecting, 
there are blocking options on android phones, but these don't stop calls connecting and voicemails being left.

You have blocked on the phone, which is great, and that is why you were not notified of the incoming call at the time, the mobile provider does still deal with a call if the phone does not answer it.

As others have noted, mobile network provider would be the best step forward, there is scope for blacklisting a number, alternatively another good suggestion is consider getting a new number.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, contact the phone carriers account holder for that line, if it's not you. Either you or they need to call carrier and inform them you would like to block a phone number on your account.

This is s true call block.